# C++ combine elements of a vector

Tags: c++, combinations, permutation

I have a vector h, within the vector i have batteries some that are working **w** and some that are not working **z**. In order for my torch lamp to start i need two batteries from w and each battery is unique as in real life condition. how can i use combination to get a good pair of working batteries in less tries possible.

I am actually learning algorithm/programming and have no clue how to approach it , i did some research on nextPermutation() but i don't understand it and dont thin it resolves the problem. i assume i could do something like:

```
for(w, z) in h:
    nextPermutation(w,z)
```

since each  battery is unique if i have for example [A B C D], AB = BA and AC =CA so i dont want to repeat it like that.

Comment: Is this homework? There's an easy solution that does not involve permutations.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm not really! How i cant think of anything without permutation maybe because i am not that familiar with c++.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the problem. If the point is to try every battery with every other battery until you find a pair that works, it's as simple as `for (int i = 0; i < size-1; ++i) for (int j = i + 1; j < size; ++j) { tryTwoBatteries(h[i], h[j]; }`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this is correct, but i am looking for an optimised one that can get the working pair in less tries. i want to get the working pair without necessarilyy comparing all the batteries in the vector.

Comment: Unless you get some additional information from an unsuccessful test, I don't see how you can do better than brute force. Whatever algorithm you come up with, it's always possible to construct input where the only working pair is the one that algorithm tries last.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes i did run into unsuccessful ones, when there are many faulty it always returns i faulty and one that is working, but when there are many good one it always return a good pair . Basically the test sets are different in ratio good/faulty. " Whatever algorithm you come up with, it's always possible to construct input where the only working pair is the one that algorithm tries last" How so? Thanks.

Comment: Well, first I run your algorithm on "all faulty" input and make note of which pairs it tries before reporting "no good pair found". Then I give it an array with all faulty batteries, except for the two that it tried at the very end the first time round, right before giving up. If testing good+bad battery is indistinguishable from bad+bad, your algorithm will have to try all the same pairs again, until it finds the good pair at the very end. Therefore, it's impossible to construct an algorithm doing better than `O(N^2)` in the worst case.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik i am not sure to understand, but i will try as you said. Thanks.